# Restricting possible values of an input to a derived type based on the input of a previous type( TypeScript )

Tags: typescript

In functional programming with types you often can restrict types in your application to provided values of input.

However I'm at a loss in how to do this with TypeScript with the possible values of the keys for a Map.

Consider the following:

```
const match = <T, V, R>(p : (x : V) => T, ... c : Array< [T, (x : V) => R] >) : (x : V) => R => {
  const cases = new Map(c);
  return (x : any) => cases.get(p(x))(x);
}
```

A more human readable format:

```
const match = <Row, Value, ReturnType>(p : (x : Value) => Row, ...c : Array< [Row, (x : Value) => ReturnType] >) : (x : Value) => ReturnType => {
  const cases = new Map(c);
  return x => cases.get(p(x))(x);
}
```

However there is a problem with this notation as it isn't actually doing what is intended to be done:

```
match(x => Math.random() > 0.5 ? "foo" : "bar", ["baz", x => x])
```

This should, in a sufficiently advanced Typing system be able to be an error, however in TypeScript it is not detecting that the "foo" or "bar" values are not any of the expected values and would actually cause the code to throw.

A more in depth example:

```
const validDouble = match( x => x * 2,
[4, x => "four"],
[6, x => "six"]
)

validDouble(4) // TS ERROR: 8 is not a valid value for Type ROW (4 | 6)
validDouble(2) // "four", no TS Error
```

I know I can't enforce the rest parameter to be a forced value of arrays(I could however wrap it in an enforced array and require extra characters from the developer), but I am curious if there is a way to enforce that the values in the row match the output values in the predicate function?

EDIT: Yes I know this throws on a non matching input. That logic is EASY to insert with conditionals or try catches and turning this into a matchMaybe, however this example was simplified because that has no impact or implication on the typing system available in TypeScript

Comment: Corrected,  thanks

Comment: I didn't dive too deeply, but basically you want to restrict return values of the first parameter (which is a function) to `"baz"`? Am I right?

Comment: If I have multiple key values in the set it should only be one of the values, otherwise TS should throw an error about imcompatible types

Comment: Ok so it should be a union, give me a few minutes..

Comment: Robert can you please explain in a couple of words what this function actually should do. I see it's named `match`, but what does it matches?

Comment: When given a predicate and a set of acceptable answers to transformation, on given valid inout it will return a transformation applied to the input. If given a non defined result from the predicate it should throw, however using the typing system it should instead just not allow it for pre defined scenarios(developer space, not non user)

Comment: Doesn't look like a couple of words :) Anyway, I've made some progress. But the type actually has multiple problems, solved some of them but not all.

Comment: That's the thing... the function is fine. The type is as good as I could get it(allows all valid types), however the type is kit restricting the possible values of the predicate to the valid values of the map for known examples. When I wake up in the morni g I can update this with a more in depth example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here is the fixed function (may need some tidy-up and probably improvements).

```
const match = <
Row extends string | number,
Value,
ReturnType,
V extends (x: Value) => ReturnType,
C extends [...[Row, V][]],
>
(
predicate: (x: Value) => Row,
...c: C & [...[Row, V][]]
): (x: Value) => ReturnType => {

const cases = new Map<Row, V>(c);

return x =>
// put a runtime check below instead of asserting 
    // non-undefined value with `!` 
    cases.get(predicate(x))!(x)
}

match(x => 'baz', ["baz", (x: any) => x]) // ok
match(x => 'qwe', ["baz", (x: any) => x]) // err
match(x => 'qwe', ["baz", (x: any) => x], ["qwe", (x: any) => x]) //ok
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20match%20%3D%20%3C%0ARow%20extends%20string%20%7C%20number%2C%0AValue%2C%0AReturnType%2C%0AV%20extends%20(x%3A%20Value)%20%3D%3E%20ReturnType%2C%0AC%20extends%20%5B...%5BRow%2C%20V%5D%5B%5D%5D%2C%0A%3E%0A(%0Apredicate%3A%20(x%3A%20Value)%20%3D%3E%20Row%2C%0A...c%3A%20C%20%26%20%5B...%5BRow%2C%20V%5D%5B%5D%5D%0A)%3A%20(x%3A%20Value)%20%3D%3E%20ReturnType%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%0Aconst%20cases%20%3D%20new%20Map%3CRow%2C%20V%3E(c)%3B%0A%0Areturn%20x%20%3D%3E%0A%2F%2F%20put%20a%20runtime%20check%20below%20instead%20of%20asserting%20%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20non-undefined%20value%20with%20%60!%60%20%0A%20%20%20%20cases.get(predicate(x))!(x)%0A%7D%0A%0Amatch(x%20%3D%3E%20'baz'%2C%20%5B%22baz%22%2C%20(x%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20x%5D)%20%2F%2F%20ok%0Amatch(x%20%3D%3E%20'qwe'%2C%20%5B%22baz%22%2C%20(x%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20x%5D)%20%2F%2F%20err%0Amatch(x%20%3D%3E%20'qwe'%2C%20%5B%22baz%22%2C%20(x%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20x%5D%2C%20%5B%22qwe%22%2C%20(x%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20x%5D)%20%2F%2Fok%0A%0A%2F%2F%20number%20keys%3A%0Amatch(x%20%3D%3E%201%2C%20%5B1%2C%20(x%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20x%5D)%20%2F%2F%20ok%0Amatch(x%20%3D%3E%202%2C%20%5B1%2C%20(x%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20x%5D)%20%2F%2F%20err%0Amatch(x%20%3D%3E%202%2C%20%5B1%2C%20(x%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20x%5D%2C%20%5B2%2C%20(x%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20x%5D)%20%2F%2Fok)

The first problem was that rest parameter should be a tuple. The second problem was to place type parameters correctly so that everything infers correctly.

P.S. Complex types in typescript are hard. I feel lack of the documentation on type parameters, hence I always feel inconfidence about them (I think others do as well).

Comment: I am not asking for the function to be fixed. This is a question about types and type enforcement on derived types

Comment: @RobertMennell Your original question was literally this: *In functional programming with types you often can restrict types in your application to provided values of input. However I'm at a loss in how to do this with TypeScript.*. To me it means that you want to know *how to do this with TypeScript*. And I showed it. I also provided a note about the lack of documentation on how type params work (even in [spec](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.6)). Your comment actually doesnt make it more clear what you really want. And that level of gratefulness doesnt help

Comment: if you reread the edits you missed how that's background information. I have, since the beginning, been looking how to limit output values of the predict based on the key value of the map

Comment: @RobertMennell And don't last 3 lines of the code block in my answer show that output values of the predicate **are** limited based on the keys of the map? I've also just added a link to the playground.

Comment: If you ran the example o provide it does the same thing. I want the TypeScript compiler and inspector to prevent it, not a runtime error

Comment: @RobertMennell What runtime error? I didn't change *anything* that relates to runtime. But the most important thing, there IS a typecheck error that WILL prevent compilation. Have you even visited the playground?

Comment: I have not. I'll visit the playground and recheck with my TS install when I get home tomorrow. I'll visit it now on my phone

Comment: @RobertMennell Now I see what's the reason of this misunderstanding. I believe you can visit it from your phone as well. And no, I've just re-checked your code, and it doesn't do the same (doesn't produce relevant type error).

Comment: @RobertMennell Would be great if at least you could tell me if the playground is displaying what you've meant or not.

Comment: Sorry lost comment apparently got lost to the ethos. The playground is displaying what I want as long as I use an array. I kind of want to test with a rest parameter but otherwise I'm going to at least upvote

Comment: @RobertMennell thanks for the upvote. However the answer addresses your question as it is (I can't know what you *also* want inside your head, can I). So you should accept it. This is not about me personally or my scores, but it's how you should behave on SO. If you have another problem, post it in another question, and we'll try to examine it there.

Comment: The problem is 8 cant see if there is an error or not in my phone... inly the TS and the final output

Comment: So the problem I currently have is that this only works with string values, not all valid Map keys. That's what I'm trying to go for

Comment: @RobertMennell you could just replace `Row extends string` with `Row extends string | number`.

Comment: String | number | object... fair enough. I'll give it an acceptance

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work for Objects or Symbols but it works for primitive types. I'll look more into that myself though. Thanks!